# Core Coupled Memory executable on STM32F4xx?

Tags: embedded, stm32

Trying to run code from a STM32F429s CCM but I always get a Hard Fault with the IBUSERR flag set as soon as I hit the first instruction in the CCM.

The instruction is valid and well aligned. 
Is it possible that the STM32F4xx does not allow execution from the CCM? (Data access works well).

alios

Comment: On this part the CCM has a performance advantage only when used to access data concurrently with DMA access to other on-chip memory by avoiding bus contention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CCM in these parts is only connected to the data bus. Instructions cannot be fetched from this memory -- only flash memory, SRAM1, and external memory should be used for code.

[image: System architecture for STM32F42xxx and STM32F43xxx devices]

For more information, refer to section 2.1 ("System Architecture") of [the reference manual](http://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020.pdf), which is where the above image came from.

Comment: Thnx! On the STM32F3 it was also possible to run code from there.

Comment: But you can run from the SRAM. Place the critical routines there and stack and data in thew CCM - this is most efficient way to handle the critical routines.

Comment: @Clifford Are you sure? The sections on the I-bus and S-bus explicitly mention fetching instructions; the section on the D-bus, by contrast, does not. It says that the target is "memory containing code or data", but that seems like it's in reference to the D-bus's use for literal data loads.

Comment: @duskwuff : I stand corrected - the D-Bus allows data and debug access to code space, _not execution_.  It is more clearly explained at http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.100166_0001_00_en/Chunk419908413.html, though somewhat unhelpfully ST have used slightly different nomenclature.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 : While you can run from SRAM1, if you are simultaneously fetching data from SRAM1 the bus contention will slow execution compared with executing from flash with its separate I/D buses from the accelerator.  The part is optimised for execution from flash.  RAM execution is largely only useful for dynamically loaded code on this part rather then for performance.

Comment: @Clifford - you are wrong. The most efficient configuration is - code in the SRAM1, DATA + STACK in the CCM. Code from the SRAM1 is fetched via the I-BUS, data from the CCMNAM via the D-BUS. The execution from the FLASH is efficient as the bus is wide and pipeline effective - but only when program flows normally. Exceptions (including interrupts) destroy this "normal" flow and the interrupt latency is significantly larger  when the routine is executed from the FLASH. If the exception routine is called very often or the latency is important - it is wise to have it in the SRAM

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Flash is dual-port; SRAM1 is single-port. This makes code which makes heavy use of the literal pool run slower from SRAM1, because instruction fetches are delayed by accesses to the literal pool.

Comment: @Clifford `@duskwuff : I stand corrected - the D-Bus allows data and debug access to code space, not execution.` As i remember you had a very strong right opposite opinion two hours before. You should not have been changing your comments.

Comment: @duskwuff - I think you do not understand. I wrote about well written software. Any possible advantages of the architecture can be wasted by the useless programmers. In this case it does not matter where the code and data are located

Comment: @PeterJ_01 : I am not sure of your objection.  That is what "I stand corrected" means - the change is clearly flagged.  I deleted the original comments because a read might not get past that and be mislead.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 : Are you sure - would fetching immediate operands from flash not be faster than for code executing in SRAM1, because the instruction and operand can be fetched concurrently?  The improvement would be marginal at best and possibly not worth the development effort and complexity.  Moreover the RAM is already a severely limited resource - often you will have better use for it that such marginal gains. It looks at best a premature optimization to me.

Comment: @Clifford interrupt latency is a very important factor in many applications. Interrupt routine executed from the FLASH will be invoked significantly slower than from the RAM. In this case it does not matter how huge the development effort is - it just has to be done properly.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 : I think we are off topic.

Comment: Right now I habe no real performance issues. The initial thinking was to a) not waste the CCM and b) to have kind of harvardish Memory Layout (Code in CCM, Data in Main SRAM). 

I now placed the freertos data structures + main and task stacks into CCM and use main SRAM for "the rest". Think this is a useful layout, so (esp. the Ethernet MAC) DMA can work on the SRAM while other Tasks work on the CCM for data.